# neo4j-spatial - Unable to create simple point layer via neo4j REST API

Tags: java, neo4j, jersey, neo4j-spatial

I'm following [the neo4j spatial documentation](http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-create-a-pointlayer) together with a [test file](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/SpatialPluginFunctionalTest.java#L66) on github to set a neo4j spatial pointlayer structure up.
I am using neo4j 2.0.2 on Windows 7, cloned the spatial 2.0.2. repository and installed the spatial plugin into my \plugins folder (the plugin is also listed under the plugins section of the neo4j browser).

I am trying to set a point index up by executing the following code (using Jersey):

```
final String txUri = "http://localhost:7575/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer"; 
        WebResource resource = Client.create().resource( txUri );

        String payload = "{\"layer\":\"geom\", \"lat\":\"lat\", \"lon\":\"lon\"}";
            ClientResponse response = resource
                    .entity( payload )
                    .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+"; charset=UTF-8")
                    .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                    .post( ClientResponse.class );

        return response.getEntity( String.class );
```

As demanded in the docs, I included "accept=appliaction/json", "Content-type=application/json" and the UTF-8 as encoding in the POST header. I copied the body of the POST request from the test file on github. However I get a status 500 error:

> > com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> >       com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
> >       com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
> >       com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
> >       com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
> >       com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:560)
> >       com.youtube.rest.status.V1_status.createSpatialIndex(V1_status.java:67)
> >       com.youtube.rest.status.V1_status.returnTitle(V1_status.java:24)
> >       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
> >       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
> >       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
> >       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
> >       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
> >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >     root cause
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>     java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>     java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>     java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>     com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:238)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
>     com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
>     com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:560)
>     com.youtube.rest.status.V1_status.createSpatialIndex(V1_status.java:67)
>     com.youtube.rest.status.V1_status.returnTitle(V1_status.java:24)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I thought it might be a problem with my tomcat server. But other URLs of the webservice are working as intended. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks as if you're using a non-standard port? 7575 ?

Comment: Awesome. I just copied the code from the source file and did not question whether the port is correct or not (port 7575 is also used in the docs). So changing it to 7474 worked for me.